# Play Sound If Condition is Met

Tags: r

I installed `beepr` library and I need to run `beep()` only if condition is met, example:

```
library(beepr)

test=data.frame(a=1,b=2)
ifelse(test$b==2,beep(1),beep(2))
```

> Error in rep(yes, length.out = len) :
> attempt to replicate an object of type 'externalptr'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ifelse` sound is generated along with the error. The issue with `ifelse` is that it returns the data of same type as the `test` value.

From `?ifelse` -

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test.

Since `beep` returns an output different than the `test` it returns an error.

Use `if`/`else` -

```
library(beepr)
test=data.frame(a=1,b=2)
if(test$b==2) beep(1) else beep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks very much you solve for me a problem that I was working on it for more than 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse` is not good here, it modified each value, but it needs to retain the same data type.

There for use `ifelse`:

```
if(2 %in% test$b) beep(1) else beep(2)
```

I used `in` since you probably need `in` here.